# Unable to import a component using material-ui via webpack module federation

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, webpack-5, webpack-module-federation

A simple POC where we have a react app `host_ui` as host and `material_components` as a remote. `material_ui` exposes a component `NavBar`.

```
import React from 'react';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu';

const NavBar = () => {

  return (
    <AppBar position="static">
      <Toolbar>
        <IconButton edge="start" color="inherit" aria-label="menu">
          <MenuIcon />
        </IconButton>
        <Typography variant="h6">
          News
          </Typography>
        <Button color="inherit">Login</Button>
      </Toolbar>
    </AppBar>
  );
}

export default NavBar;
```

Importing it in the host throws the error:

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
    at resolveDispatcher (react.development.js:1476)
    at Object.useContext (react.development.js:1484)
    at useTheme (useTheme.js:10)
    at useStyles (makeStyles.js:237)
    at WithStyles(ForwardRef(AppBar)) (withStyles.js:68)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14985)
    at updateForwardRef (react-dom.development.js:17044)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:19098)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994)

react-dom.development.js:20085 The above error occurred in the <WithStyles(ForwardRef(AppBar))> component:

    at WithStyles(ForwardRef(AppBar)) (webpack://material_components/./node_modules/@material-ui/styles/esm/withStyles/withStyles.js?:61:31)
    at NavBar
    at Suspense
    at div
    at App

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.

Uncaught Error: A cross-origin error was thrown. React doesn't have access to the actual error object in development. See https://reactjs.org/link/crossorigin-error for more information.
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4005)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23959)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22771)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:22702)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:22665)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:22288)
    at eval (react-dom.development.js:11327)
    at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:646)
    at runWithPriority$1 (react-dom.development.js:11276)
```

Though it works fine if we use only html from NavBar component. Is there something extra that needs to be done for using `material-ui` in module federation.

Comment: please add remotes exposed in webpack config & imports in code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have this issue also, it's happening to me when **APP1** was with `React=17.0.0` and **APP2** was with `React=17.0.2`. Basically, I had a special config to care of this case and download a new copy of React but for some reason, it's didn't work correctly with `MUI`.

It's works for me only when I set the same version of react for both apps and set that config for both apps in the ModuleFedration settings:

```
  shared: {
    react: {
    singleton: true,
    requiredVersion: deps["react"],
    },
    "react-dom": {
       singleton: true,
       requiredVersion: deps["react-dom"],
    }
  }
```

I open a issue in the MUI github paga : https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/29038#issuecomment-943317668

Answer (score 0):

Configure the Module Federation for your nav component in this way:

```
new ModuleFederationPlugin({
  name: "NavApp",
  filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
  exposes:{
    './NavComponent':'./src/{root of the nav project}'
  },
  shared: {
    ...deps,
    react: {
      singleton: true,
      requiredVersion: deps.react,
    },
    "react-dom": {
      singleton: true,
      requiredVersion: deps["react-dom"],
    },
  },
})
```

Configure the Module Federation for the application that is consuming the Nav this way:

```
`new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: "Appliaction",
      remotes: {
        NavApp: 'NavApp@http://localhost:{port that is running your Nav 
        application}/remoteEntry.js',    
      },
      shared: {
        ...deps,
        react: {
          singleton: true,
          requiredVersion: deps.react,
        },
        "react-dom": {
          singleton: true,
          requiredVersion: deps["react-dom"],
        },
      },`
```

Configure your nav package as follows:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.13.14",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.13.13",
    "add": "^2.0.6",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "css-loader": "^5.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.1",
    "react-router": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "webpack": "^5.30.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.6.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2",
    "yarn": "^1.22.10",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.1.5",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.1.5",
    "@material-ui/core": "^5.0.0-alpha.28",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^5.0.0-alpha.28",
    "@material-ui/styles": "^4.10.0",
    "@material-ui/system": "^4.11.3",
    "react": "^16.13.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.0",
    "serve": "^11.3.0"
  }
```

**Do not change the version of react or react-dom, if you have other dependencies, add also**

Configure the package of your main application (which is consuming the Nav) like this:

```
   "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.13.14",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.13.13",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "css-loader": "^5.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.1",
    "react-router": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "webpack": "^5.30.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.6.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.9.5",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^5.1.1",
    "react": "^16.13.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.0",
    "serve": "^11.3.0"
  }
```

**Do not change the version of react or react-dom, if you have other dependencies, add also**

Delete the node_modules folder and delete the file yarn.lock or package-lock.json, from both applications. From a Yarn or Npm install again in the applications (to install the new dependencies). Following these changes, everything should work.